# I can't run tensorflow with GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am a beginner in deep learning and I've been trying to pip install tensorflow and run it using my laptop's GPU (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060). So I tried following the steps on the following website: [https://towardsdatascience.com/setup-an-environment-for-machine-learning-and-deep-learning-with-anaconda-in-windows-5d7134a3db10](https://stackoverflow.com)
I downloaded GeForce Experience, already had anaconda, installed CUDA toolkit and cuDNN. I'm currently using windows 11 so upon installing I chose the matching versions. for Cuda, I tried both 11 and 12. When I check if the install went well with nvcc --version, the following appears(Coda12):

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_13_19:42:34_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.91
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.32965470_0

I installed everything that I believed was needed but then when I check weither the GPU is being used, by entering:

`tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")`

I get an empty list as an output.
I tried both with and without creating an environment but the result doesn't change.
Can someone help with that please?

I downloaded everything that I believed was needed and was expecting tensorflow to use the laptop's GPU.

Comment: Latest TensorfFlow requires cudatoolkit 11.8 and cuDNN 8.6. Check the version of what you installed, and change it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I'm on windows11 and so when check that box the only version of CUDA I'm allowed to download seems to be CUDA12.2.0 and then when cuDNN website says cuDNN v8.9.3 is the version compatible for CUDA12. Should I still find a way to download  cudatoolkit 11.8 and cuDNN 8.6?

Comment: [Cuda Toolkit 11.8](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive) and the list of [cuDNN archives](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) (look for cudnn 8.6 for CUDA 11.x)

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot find the specific Tensorflow version mentioned above, I highly suspect that the problem is the unsupported version of the Tensorflow-GPU library for Windows OS.

According to the official Tensorflow website(https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu), you can find the notice: **GPU support on native-Windows is only available for 2.10 or earlier versions.**